# How to change constraint of view in iOS swift 4?

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints, constants, swift4

I have write this code for change constraint of view height, but it is not working. This change my view height without animation and change it immediately.

```
//MARK:Scrollview delegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        self.topView.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
            self.topViewHeight.constant = 64
            self.topView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: is the constant before the animation bigger or smaller than 64?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ before is bigger than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the new constraint constant outside of the `UIView.animate`, and also call `setNeedsLayout()`. Moreover, I guess you just want to call that animation once at the beginning, so you can implement a simple guard to test if it has been already expanded (or collapsed, depends on what you are trying to do).

```
var isTopViewCollapsed = false

//MARK:Scrollview delegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && !isTopViewCollapsed {
        isTopViewCollapsed = true
        self.topView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.topViewHeight.constant = 64
        // you need to tell the autolayout that constraints been changed 
        self.topView.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
            self.topView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: change constant immediately

Comment: @reza_khalafi try now